# onkeypress should execute only if the value changed

Tags: javascript

I have a function say jsFunEnter(e)

```
<input name="name" id="id" onkeypress="jsFunEnter(event)"  size="2" value="13"/>

function jsFunEnter(e)
{
if (e.keyCode == 13) 
     {
       callAnother();
     }
}
```

In short I don't need to call the function jsFunEnter(e) on pressing enter key, if the value not changed. eg: if I have '7' in the textbox. I change '7' to '8' and press enter the function  should execute. But if I change '7' and enter '7' again and press enter won't call the function.

Comment: Store the last know value and see if it changed or use defaultValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the old value on another global variable and check for change at the beginning of your method. Update the global variable at the end of your method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your previous value and check it against the new one:

```
var oldInput;

function jsFunEnter(e)
{
     if (e.keyCode == 13) 
     {
       newInput = document.getElementById("id").value;
       if (newInput != oldInput) {
           oldInput=newInput;
           callAnother();
       }

     }
}
```